# How (if possible) can I change the color of the grey tabs of my terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, macosx

I would like to change the color of the tabs in my bashrc. I know the background I can do with `setterm -term linux -back <background_colour> -fore <text_color> -clear`, but how can I change the tab color (see figure for example of what I'm looking for)?

[image]

Comment: Is this really a gnome-terminal running on Mac? gnome-terminal does not offer this possibility. On Mac, iTerm2 allows you to change the tab's color by right-clicking on the tab.